# Change ViewModel property through mouse event in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a bunch of items on a canvas. When I click on one, I want it to set its "Selected" property to true, display an adorner over it, and set the "Selected" property to false to the other items.

In my XAML I have this :

```
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:DragOnCanvasBehavior
                    DraggableItem="{Binding}">
                    <behaviors:DragOnCanvasBehavior.MouseOverAdornerTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border
                                DataContext="DraggableBorder"
                                BorderBrush="#B0000000"
                                BorderThickness="3"
                                Width="{Binding Path=Width}"
                                Height="{Binding Path=Height}"></Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </behaviors:DragOnCanvasBehavior.MouseOverAdornerTemplate>
                    <behaviors:DragOnCanvasBehavior.SelectedAdornerTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border
                                DataContext="DraggableBorder"
                                BorderBrush="#FF34619E"
                                BorderThickness="3"
                                Width="{Binding Path=Width}"
                                Height="{Binding Path=Height}"
                                Visibility="{Binding Path=Selected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"></Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </behaviors:DragOnCanvasBehavior.SelectedAdornerTemplate>

                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <!-- Dragging and mouse over/out events like this : -->
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction CommandName="StartDrag" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </behaviors:DragOnCanvasBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Border>
    </AdornerDecorator>
</DataTemplate>
```

I imagine that somewhere in the behavior's events, I should invoke a command when the viewmodel's "Selected" property has changed, but I have no idea how to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have yielded and I now handle the mouse events through the behavior directly.

I still have some problems, though : [Bind adorner property to viewmodel property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093856/bind-adorner-property-to-viewmodel-property)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a listview with a control template that leverages a canvas.

Then use the selecteditem property.

Comment: Do you think it would be easier, or that it's just impossible otherwise? Because it's mostly a "learning" project so I don't care much if it's "just" difficult.